# WPF. How to write rounded corners for Grid in the Grid Style

Tags: wpf, grid, styles, rounded-corners

I know how to write rounded corners with border in the Grid, but do not know how to do it with Grid style, I was thinking to use template, but Grid doesn't has it, it is even possible to write rounded corners in the Grid Style or not? If yes, maybe someone can show how to do it?

Comment: Why not just put a border around your grid?

Answer (score 1):

The `Grid` control does not supprt `CornerRadius` and it is not possible change the template of the `Grid` control.

You would have to either create your own custom `Grid` control or wrap your `Grid` in a `Border` control:

```
<Border CornerRadius="5">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```